# Background Color stripes in a single row <tr> element in a table

Tags: html, css

I have a table with a single row and 3 cells. I am looking to change the color of the entire row which will have 3 stripes. I am not sure how to go about it.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>first cell</td>
    <td>second cell</td>
    <td>third cell</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Had it been a div I would have placed 3 div inside it and I would be able to do something like this:

```
    <style>
    #someDiv{
        border: 1px;
       // background-color: grey;
        width:100%;
        height:102px;
    }
    #divthree{
        background-color:green;
        height:34px;
    }
    #divone{
        background-color:#FF6600;
        height:34px;
    }
    #divtwo{
        background-color:white;
        height:34px;
    }
</style>

<div id="someDiv">
    <div id="divone"></div>
    <div id="divtwo"></div>
    <div id="divthree"></div>
</div>
```

Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/5mdEK/

Here's how it worked out: http://jsfiddle.net/H4Hr7/

Comment: Your added fiddle has 3 row, your `table` has just one, containing 3 columns. these are not like each other.

Comment: you need to add 3 <tr> tags for it to look similar to the fiddle example

Comment: I know they are not, that was just an example as to how the expected output was..Anyways I will update my answer with a new fiddle

Comment: @Rohit: three <tr> are not required. I just updated the answer with the new fiddle..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could easily be achieved by using CSS Gradients.

This way you can create a striped background for a single element.

See: http://css-tricks.com/striped-background-gradients/

If you are needing to set a different background for each  without extra classes or anything you can use advanced selectors like

td:nth-child(2)

See: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp

Comment: Thanks the CSS gradients helped.. I will need to check if this compatible with all the browsers..

Comment: You can use [this gradient generator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) to create complex and cross browser gradients with ease.

Answer (score 2):

```
td:nth-child(even) {background: #CCC}
td:nth-child(odd) {background: #FFF}
```

or

```
col:nth-child(2n) {background: #CCC}
```

See:
http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd.en.html

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code:

```
<style>
    #table{
        border: 1px;
       // background-color: grey;
        width:100%;
        height:102px;
    }
    #tdthree{
        background-color:green;
        height:34px;
    }
    #tdone{
        background-color:#FF6600;
        height:34px;
    }
    #tdtwo{
        background-color:white;
        height:34px;
    }
</style>

<table width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td id="tdone">first cell</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="tdtwo">first cell</td>
  <tr>
  </tr>
    <td id="tdthree">first cell</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
  <tr>
      <td>first cell</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>first cell</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>first cell</td>
  </tr>  
</table>
```

## css

```
table tr:nth-child(1) {
    background-color: red;
}
table tr:nth-child(2) {
    background-color: white;
}
table tr:nth-child(3) {
    background-color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.Table
{
    display: table;
}
.Title
{
    display: table-caption;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: larger;
}
.Heading
{
    display: table-row;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}
.Row
{
    display: table-row;
}
.Cell
{
    display: table-cell;
    border: solid;
    border-width: thin;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}
```

see the [Link Demo and Full Source](http://www.edufeeder.com)